# Is there a way to stop laravel files in phpunit getting infected by Trajon virus

Tags: laravel, web, phpunit, virus

I find unexpected files different from what i uploaded in phpunit laravel files.
Even emails in cpanel are manipulated.

**Some of the created files**

/home/~/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/to.php

/home/~/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/X_Bsend.php

/home/~/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/unit.php

/home/~/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/tshop.php

/home/~/public_html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/smtpp8.php

Anyone who can help stop this Attack on laravel, please help

Comment: It's not Laravel. It is either your server or your PC that is being effected.

Comment: I suspect you're affected by https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-9841/. You should, among other things, make sure your webserver is not configured to serve the non-public folders of Laravel. Only `public` should be exposed to the internet.

Comment: Odd, my CVE link broke. https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-9841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install composer dependencies use the --no-dev flag. `composer install --no-dev` you don't want dev dependencies in your production environment.

This will result in you not having phpunit in your vendor directory.

**Disclaimer: This is not a virus fix, your vulnerablity could be elsewhere.**

Comment: This answer isn't super useful. The issue isn't necessarily that PHPUnit is installed. The issue is that compromised files have been slipped into the PHPUnit folders. It *may* have absolutely nothing to do with PHPUnit itself. I found a CVE that may apply, but it's fundamentally a problem with accidentally putting the `vendor` directory accessible via the web.